# VK поделиться и знак $

Tags: вконтакте

Есть кнопка поделиться в VK, всё работает, но возникает небольшая проблема со знаком доллара на этапе расшаривания:

вместо $ отображается html код

[image: вместо $ показывает html код]

Как это исправить?

код в rails приложении

```
      javascript:
        document.write(VK.Share.button({
          url: "#{request.original_url}",
          title: "#{@product.title}",
          description: "#{@product.seo_description}",
          image: "#{image_path @product.photos.first.image.url}"
          },
          {type:'custom',
          text: "<i class='icon-vk'></i>"}
        ));

@product.seo_description => 'Only 200$'
в html коде `description: "Only 200.0$"
```

Comment: Проблема скорее всего на вашей стороне. Но если вы не покажете ваш код, нам останется только догадываться.